# SQL How to Update in Batches

Tags: sql, ssms

so I'm faced with a situation where I have a bunch of blank data. I have say 1000 rows, and I need to assign various data to the rows. Say I have a column called "Cost" and the DBName is "Parts".

What I need to do, is to have 150 Entries with a cost of 10, 250 entries with a cost of 20, 300 entries with a cost of 30, and 300 entries with a cost of 40.

I don't want to re-update any values. So after updating the top 150 with a cost of 10, I want this excluded from the remaining results.

What is the general syntax or strategy for accomplishing something like that?

Comment: If, as you say, you have "blank" data, which you are going to update in batches, then part of your criteria for each subsequent update would just include only those rows where the data is still "blank".  To be honest, you will probably get better assistance from others if you include either some sample data, or at least the structure of the table that you are working with, and what your criteria will be for determining the "top" rows

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to use the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to index your records by whatever ordering criteria you need. An example is below, but there are lots of ways to write similar behaviour.

```
DECLARE @exampleTable TABLE (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Cost DECIMAL(10, 2))

;WITH numberedRows AS (
  SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id ASC) RowNum -- ordering criteria go in here 
  FROM @exampleTable
)
UPDATE e
SET e.Cost = CASE
               WHEN n.RowNum <= 150 THEN 10
               WHEN n.RowNum <= 400 THEN 20
               WHEN n.RowNum <= 700 THEN 30
               WHEN n.RowNum <= 1000 THEN 40
               ELSE 0 -- default cost for remaining items here
             END
FROM @exampleTable e
INNER JOIN numberedRows n ON n.Id = e.Id
```